# Representations of bijective transformations of the least residue system modulo m

Tags: polynomials, finite-groups

Let us denote (as usual) $\mathbb{Z}_m$ the least residue system modulo $m$, and let $f:\mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ be an arbitrary bijective function.  Is there a universal representation of such a function, for example, in the form of polynomials, that is for example
$$
f(x)=a_0 x^n+a_1 x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x+a_n \, (\mathrm{mod} \, m) \, ?
$$
If there is no such representation, are other representations possible?

Comment: And what will be if we replace bijective functions (i.e. permutations) with cyclic permutations of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me use the example $m=p^2$ where $p$ is prime.

Denote by $I\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}[x]$ the ideal of polynomials that are the zero function.

Let $J=\langle\, p(x^p-x)\;,\;(x^p-x)^2\,\rangle$.

Now, $J\subseteq I$.

Therefore
$\left|\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}[x]}{I}\right|\leq\left|\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}[x]}{J}\right|=p^{3p}$.

$\\$

The number of cycles of length $p^2$ in $S_{p^2}$ is

$(p^2-1)!>\!\!>p^{3p}$

asymptotically for $p\to\infty$.